# Datatables only shows data after click on column length dropdown or typing on filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and my data only shows when I click on the column length dropdown or when I type a text in filter input.

Javascript:

```
var oArtikliData = $.getJson('json.php?json=artikli');
oArtikliTable = $('#tbl_artikli').DataTable(
{   
    "aaData": oArtikliData,
    "columnDefs": 
    [
        { 
            /* REDNI BROJ */
            "targets": 0,   
            "data": "r_br" 
        },
        { 
            /* PROIZVOĐAČ */
            "targets": 1,   
            "data": "proizvodjac" 
        },
        { 
            /* MODEL */
            "targets": 2,       
            "data": "naziv"
        },
        { 
            /* CIJENA BEZ PDV */
            "targets": 3,       
            "data": "cijena_bezPDV"
        }
    ],
    "dom": 'R<"pdf_button"><"clear">lfrtip',
    "autoWidth": true,
    'iDisplayLength': 50,
    "lengthMenu": [[1,5,10, 25, 50], [1,5,10, 25, 50]]

    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table style="margin-top:15px;" id="tbl_artikli" class="table table-striped table-bordered display">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="nohover custom_table_header">
                                    <th>R.br.</th>
                                    <th>Proizvođač</th>
                                    <th>Model</th>
                                    <th>Cijena bez PDV-a</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

I am using the latest jQuery, I have tried in Chrome and Firefox, but the issue is still present.

Why does my data only appear under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Your table is initialized before the data is retrieved from remote source, that is why no data shows initially. Also there is extra closing bracket `}` that should be removed.

Use the following code instead:

```
var oArtikliTable = $('#tbl_artikli').DataTable({   
    "ajax": {
       "url": 'json.php?json=artikli',
       "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        { 
            /* REDNI BROJ */
            "targets": 0,   
            "data": "r_br" 
        },
        { 
            /* PROIZVOĐAČ */
            "targets": 1,   
            "data": "proizvodjac" 
        },
        { 
            /* MODEL */
            "targets": 2,       
            "data": "naziv"
        },
        { 
            /* CIJENA BEZ PDV */
            "targets": 3,       
            "data": "cijena_bezPDV"
        }
    ],
    "dom": 'R<"pdf_button"><"clear">lfrtip',
    "autoWidth": true,
    'pageLength': 50,
    "lengthMenu": [[1,5,10, 25, 50], [1,5,10, 25, 50]]

});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4364m1sy/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Still not working. Im getting json data from my localhost, its small data. Im also getting this error Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Comment: @Hawkridge, can you please post a sample of your JSON data? Visit `json.php?json=artikli` and post your results.

Comment: @Hawkridge, added example to demonstrate that my solution works. Also there was extra `}` in your code that I missed.

Comment: I see that code works. Maybe is due to jQuery version because i getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in "

Comment: @Hawkridge, I outlined the reason why it happens in my answer. You need to let DataTables do the Ajax. Alternatively you need wait for response from remote source before initializing the table.

Comment: Yeah but i have same error when i enter manually data in html, without ajax.

Comment: I solved a problem. Problem was in old version of datatables. Thanx Gyrocode.com